# when I refresh the page, memory usage get more, why? and how can I fix it?

Tags: php, memory

I have a file called *`memory_usage_test.php`*. something like this:

```
// memory_usage_test.php

 <?php
   echo memory_get_usage(); 
 ?>
```

when I run that, the output is `58480` , and when I refresh the page, the output will be `58704`. why? why that get more ? and how can I fix it ?

---

**Edit:**

I do it via `var_dump()`: here is my **new file:**

```
<?php
echo memory_get_usage().'<br>'; 
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SERVER);
?>
```

here is my **output:**

```
// just different

// ---------------------------first time-------------------------

 array(31)
 {
      ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
      string(5) "62909"

      ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
      int(1435672670)
 }

// ---------------------------refreshed-------------------------

 array(32)
 {

     ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=> // This line is added
     string(9) "max-age=0"

      ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
      string(5) "63644"

      ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
      int(1435673309)
 }
```

Comment: Does it progressively increase each time you refresh? Or is it just a one-time random, non-reproducible change?

Comment: @deceze just one time !! and always it is the same, just when I run it as new window (in browser), it is `58480 `, and when I refresh the page, it will be `58704` and when I refresh the page again, still it is `58704`.

Comment: Is this reproducible on the command line using curl? My random guess would be that the browser sends more data back the second time, e.g. due to set cookies.

Comment: @deceze no no ! my file is contained just 1 line of code ! `echo memory_get_usage(); `

Comment: Yeah, I get that. Still, have you compared the requests and responses?

Comment: @deceze If you can, please try it, and tell me is it for you the same ?

Comment: I'm running the script over and over on command line and it's exactly the same every time. Haven't tried via web page.

Comment: I won't try to reproduce your issue here. I just threw out a few things off the top of my head which you could try. You're the one interested in figuring this out, so why don't you try following those leads?

Comment: @deceze I  do not understand your mean totally, just I want to say that I do not have any processing except `memory_usage_test.php`

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER)`, compare its contents between the two requests. Try `$ curl localhost/memory_usage_test.php` on some command line to see if the same problem happens there as well (curl is stateless, unlike a browser, which may rule out a bunch of possible causes).

Comment: So the answer is: because there's more data to store in memory...

Comment: @deceze aha, and that is good ? bad ? not important? For heavy websites, the difference is too much? Is it possible to I eliminate this difference?

Comment: It does not matter and is likely exactly how it should work. Until you actually notice it creating a problem, go and care about more important things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I got the same issue. This is due to browser caching.
You will see different values on each browser. As each browser has its own caching techniques.
When you open a new page, Request headers don't force cache-control parameter. when you refresh, Following parameter is passed in request Headers by your browser.

> Cache-Control - max-age=0

Even if you try with incognito mode, you ll see different result in opening link 1st time and refreshing it.
I am trying to fix this by disabling cache. Will let you know once done.

You can limit the memory usage by ini_set('memory_limit',);

Comment: The answer is smooth and without margin. that's great, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

As prompted by 'deceze' in the comments:

It appears to be the difference between a new/current request. If you go to the page in a NEW private browser window, you'll notice it goes down again. If you refresh , it goes up once and stays there.

If you compare `$_SERVER`, you'll notice things change between the two types of request.

The second request has an extra variable (at least on my machine):

```
'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => "max-age=0"
```

This might explain the tiny bit of extra memory.

Honestly the real answer here is: It doesn't matter. It's such a tiny difference and not like it constantly goes up. It's just the server handling subsequent requests differently to fresh ones (as expected), as your browser will have requested the page differently (due to caching control headers). This is normal and expected.

Comment: +1 for this sentence: *It doesn't matter. It's such a tiny difference and not like it constantly goes up*